# Summation notation and permutations

Tags: differential-geometry, summation, determinant

I have a matrix function $\Phi(t)$ with entries $\phi_{i,j}(t)$. I want to compute the derivative of its determinant. I'm computing

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \det(\Phi(t)) = \frac{d}{dt} \left[ \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^n \phi_{i, \sigma(i)}(t) \right] = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \left[ \sum_{i = 1}^n \phi'_{i, \sigma(i)}(t) \prod_{\ell \neq i} \phi_{\ell, \sigma(\ell)}(t) \right].
\end{align*}

**My question:** In the last expression, can I suppress the second summation sign?

I.e. if I write:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot  \phi'_{i, \sigma(i)}(t) \prod_{\ell \neq i} \phi_{\ell, \sigma(\ell)}(t),
\end{align*}

then will it be clear that a sum should be taken over the index $i$?

---

My guess is "yes" because the index is repeated, even though it is repeated as the argument of the permutation. And I thank you in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Do not suppress. There is absolutely no Einstein summation principle in play here.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful.